# What does the phrase "You're out of your element" mean?

Tags: catch-phrases

I heard it in The Big Lebowski movie, when Walter yells at Donny, "shut the fuck up, Donny"; then he exclaims, "You're out of your element!".

Comment: General reference: [specific quote](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=You're%20out%20of%20your%20element%20Donnie) and [the phrase in general](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+out+of+element).

Comment: i am a programmer and i saw this question in stack overflow,so i quess here in english.SE i am out of my element,no ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The references given in a comment (in [thefreedictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+out+of+element) and [urbandictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=You%27re%20out%20of%20your%20element%20Donnie)) suggest the meaning, "to feel unhappy or strange because you are in a situation that you are not familiar with", but provide no sense of *why* it should mean that.
It is a reference to [classical elements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_element), Earth, Water, Air, and Fire; as, for example, a fish out of water is out of its element.

Comment: +1 "A fish out of water" is a great example of the literal and intended meaning.

Answer (score 11):

Someone's "element" refers to their bailiwick of expertise or comfort. A doctor might be *in her element* in the operating room but *out of her element* in a garage.

The quote from The Big Lebowski can be interpreted as "This situation is not something you are comfortable or qualified to deal with."

Comment: In the lingo of the film: "Back off! You have no fucking clue what you're dealing with here".