# A word that means "in its designed environment"

Tags: single-word-requests

I've considered the use of "in-situ," which may be the best match.  In-situ seems to have a shade of meaning connoting an original location, where I am looking for something more along the lines of "Where it was meant to be."

Comment: Is the object a human creation?   Is the environment?

Comment: The object is created by an intelligent being.  I wish the word to be independent of whether the environment is natural or artificial.

Comment: An engineer might talk about "in spec" as opposed to "out of spec" to talk about a component operating within the intended context.

Answer (score 1):

"In its natural habitat" maybe?

Comment: or "in its intended place" ?

Comment: Please give an example sentence (which you can make up) using the phrase "in its natural habitat."  I think this phrase is a good fit to the question, but you need to do more than suggest an answer -- you need to show that your answer is reasonable.

Comment: Upvote because *natural* applies well. (Not to be confused with *original*.)

Comment: @Graffito, thank you for *intended*. I ran with it.

Answer (score 1):

If society is the designed environment of a human being, then **well-adjusted** should fit the bill; for a thing, so should the adjectives **fitting** or **appropriate**.

Comment: Upvote in light of the question as understood by this answer

Answer (score 0):

Technically, 
**in its intended environment**  or 
**in its intended setting**:

> ... [T]he ultimate objective of the Engineering and Manufacturing
> Development phase [is] [t]o demonstrate an affordable, supportable,
> interoperable, and producible system **in its intended environment**.
>
> – [answers.com](http://www.answers.com/Q/What_is_The_ultimate_objective_of_the_Engineering_and_Manufacturing_Development_phase),
> as in countless other browser matches for
> ‘intended-environment’.
> (Browser matches for ‘intended-setting’ are flooded by
> references to control panels and, appropriately, jewelry.)

Colloquially (and more concisely),  **in its element**:

> Be in a situation or environment that one particularly likes and in which
> one can perform well:
>
>  *She was **in her element** with doctors and hospitals.*
> – [oxforddictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/element#element__18)
>
> *A fish out of water is **out of its element**.*
> – [EL&U: What does “You're out of your element” mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/50408)

Latin surely has a perfect and obscure two-word phrase for *where intended*
while, as noted in the question, *in situ* does not apply
because it is taken to mean *in the original environment*.

Please note a subtle distinction between
an *original* and a *natural* environment.
Glibly put, *original* refers to origin
whereas *natural* refers more to essential nature.
An artificial creation may *originate* in a factory or laboratory
but everything about its purpose, including its intended setting,
is *natural* for it.